# Some times alamofireImage did't load images

Tags: ios, swift, alamofireimage

I tried this using normal

```
 winnerCell.challengeBannerURL.af_setImage(withURL:  URL(string: winnerchallengesData[indexPath.row].challengeDetails.challenge_banner_url)!)
```

It was working in normal call but not in AlamofireImage

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: self.winnerchallengesData[indexPath.row].winnerDetails.profileURL)!)
//                winnerCell.userProfile.image = UIImage(data:data!)
//
```

Comment: you might want to use SDWebImage instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data coming from the server is a stream so I have to configure this in AlamofireImage.

```
ImageResponseSerializer.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(["image/jpg","image/png","binary/octet-stream"])
```

Comment: Hi... where did you add this exactly.. please help me. I have an api with request in which I am getting .jpg image. which is not supported by AlamofireImage. How did you do it?

Comment: before getting image

Answer (score 0):

I had the case that images stopped downloading, after this setting was added to the info.plist file (on advise of a third party ad implementation);

NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia

Removing it fixed the issue.